# Multiple read a single write causes a deadlock in Linux character driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on a sample Linux module based on a character device driver (using misc driver for ease of use) and I find some unusual behavior.

I have open, read, write and release function for file operations and my misc device is named as test_device

My device has a ring buffer which can store data from a write system call and a read system call can read the data. If the buffer is full then the process invoking the write system call sleeps and if the buffer is empty then the process invoking the read system call sleeps.

There is a semaphore (with count 1 like mutex) to avoid multiple reads and hence race condition. This works well without any problem for a single read and single write process

Now I open the device as 2 instances of read using the command

```
cat /dev/test_device
```

as expected the second cat process sleeps. I have a single process to write

```
ls > /dev/test_device
```

The ls command even do not call the open system call. Could anybody kindly explain me the reason why open system call fails.

The code is listed below

```
static int hr_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    pr_info("process %i (%s) enters open\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    if (file->f_mode & FMODE_READ) down_interruptible(&rd_sem);

    pr_info("process %i (%s) leaves open\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    return 0;
}

static int hr_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    pr_info("process %i (%s) enters release\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    if (file->f_mode & FMODE_READ) up(&rd_sem);

    pr_info("process %i (%s) leaves release\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    return 0;
}

static ssize_t hr_read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_info("process %i (%s) enters read\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    if (wait_event_interruptible(wq_rd, head != tail))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;    

    if (put_user(buff[head], buffer)) 
        return -EFAULT;

    head = (head + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;

    wake_up_interruptible(&wq_wr);
    pr_info("process %i (%s) leaves read\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    return 1;
}

static ssize_t hr_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_info("process %i (%s) enters write\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    if (wait_event_interruptible(wq_wr, tail != ((head + 1) % BUFF_SIZE)))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;    

    if (get_user(buff[tail], buffer)) 
        return -EFAULT; 

    tail = (tail + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;

    wake_up_interruptible(&wq_rd);
    pr_info("process %i (%s) leaves write\n", current->pid, current->comm);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you execute "ls >/dev/test_device" you should not expect that *ls* will open your device. The shell will open it; that's what '>' does. If you are actually experiencing an open failure, it would be helpful to include the errno.

Comment: I also do this by using a program. I have a program which sits in the while loop until i get some data and the effect is the same

Comment: Create a simple program... Something like this.     main() { int fd = open("/dev/test_device", O_WRONLY); if (fd >= 0) write(fd, "FOO", 3); }  Run it under strace and discover what is happening at the system call interface. Then people here would be better able to help you.

Comment: I create a program to read from the device and run 2 instance of the same. 
The first instance and it sleeps at the read waiting for data as expected
17:30:15.967809 open("/dev/test_dev", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000015>
17:30:15.967840 read(3,
The second instance sleeps at the semaphore waiting to acquire it
17:30:30.405666 open("/dev/test_dev", O_RDONLY 

Now I do a write using command strace -ttT echo test>/dev/test_device and there is no outputs from strace.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code that you take semaphore lock in open and release it in release function. I generally don't suggest holding a lock in one function and release it another function as it might lead to locking issues or deadlock.

```
    static int hr_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
    {
    ...    
        if (file->f_mode & FMODE_READ) down_interruptible(&rd_sem);
    ...
    }

    static int hr_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
    {
     ...

       if (file->f_mode & FMODE_READ) up(&rd_sem);

     ...
    }
```

My suggestion is to move the semaphore lock(down&up) within read and write functions.

Comment: Yes even i thought it was correct but I found the implementation in this manner at this location http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs635/newstash.c